# C++ delete object as reference

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, reference, heap-memory

I have always allocated and cleaned up memory in C++ the proper way.

```
SomeObject *Object = new SomeObject();

delete Object;
```

However, recently I discovered that this compiles and executes.

```
SomeObject *Object = new SomeObject();

delete &Object;
```

So what is happening in memory here? is it cleaning up properly or is it only deleting the reference to the object, leaving it in abandoned in memory?

Comment: _"However, recently I discovered that this compiles and executes just fine."_ Looks like _undefined behavior_ for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, _it executes just fine_ is nothing more than a proper undefined behavior, isn't it? :-D (note: just joking)

Comment: Poor code but good question. Don't see a reason for downvotes.

Comment: @skypjack Sure, that's one of the possible outcomes ;-)

Comment: "and executes just fine." No it doesn't. Undefined behaviour is allowed to employ psychotronic mind control to make it seem like it's executing fine.

Comment: @n.m.: Hah, nice

Comment: Hey my fridge exploded right now, what did you guys do now actually?? Very upset!!

Comment: Probably shouldn't have said "just fine".  What I meant was it compiled and executed.

Comment: `Object` is a pointer that contains the address of the allocated memory. But `&Object` is the address of `Object` which is the address of the pointer, NOT the allocated memory. So you are passing the address of the pointer to `delete` rather than the address of the allocated memory. If `Object` is a `SomeObject*` then `&Object` is a `SomeObject**` (pointer to a pointer).

Comment: @Galik: Please do not provide technical answers in the comments section. Such "answers" bypass the peer review system which makes SO such a valuable and _verifiable_ information source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the meaning of the `&` operator depends on context. In the context you use it, it has nothing to do with references but is the *address-of* operator.

Somewhat semi-graphical the pointers and the data you allocate looks something like this:

```
+---------+     +--------+     +------------------------------+
| &Object | --> | Object | --> | Instance of SomeObject class |
+---------+     +--------+     +------------------------------+
```

That is, `&Object` points to the location where the variable `Object` is located, and `Object` points to where the instance for the `SomeObject` class is located.

When you do `delete &Object` you are telling the system to free the memory allocated for the variable `Object`, but that memory you did not allocate yourself (you allocate the memory where `Object` ***points***). Passing an invalid pointer to `delete` leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 4):

It's just wrong, plain and simple.

You didn't dynamically allocate `Object` (you only dynamically allocated the thing it points to), so by passing its address to `delete`, you give your program undefined behaviour.

Here's a roughly equivalent example:

```
int  x   = 42;
int* ptr = &x;

delete ptr;   // yikes!
```

Any unlikely thing could happen, including appearing to work or making me a more pleasant person.

Comment: Note that, after the broken `delete`, you've also leaked the `SomeObject`.

Comment: I know this, my question is what is happening on the heap during execution.

Comment: @DailyDoseOfAwesome It ended up in my fridge was exploding.

Comment: @DailyDoseOfAwesome: Nothing good, since you're deleting something from "the heap" that was never there in the first place.